# After executing a SQL statement, i get a column of data. How can I get a total of that data?

Tags: sql

I am running a query to retrieve a list of invoices that have not been approved yet.  This query is generating daily alerts via email.  The email contains an HTML table of the client name, inv #, sub-total, adjustments, final total.  I want to be able to list a summary before the table of the total sub-total, total adjustments, and total final total of the entire table.

```
ex:

Total Sub-total: 10 
Total Adj: -8 
Total Billed: 2

Sub-Total  Adj  Total
     7     -6     1
     3     -2     1
```

I tried SUM(sub-total), but it only retrieves the first sub total ("7" in this example) instead of adding them all up.  Help?

The query I am using is:

```
SELECT dbo.CurInv.subtotal AS "subtotal", dbo.CurInv.CIAdj AS "Adj",
dbo.CurInv.CIAdj+dbo.CurInv.subtotal+dbo.CurInv.CISTax AS "TotalInvoice",
SUM(dbo.CurInv.CIAdj) AS "Total Write Up(Down)" 
FROM dbo.Clients, dbo.CurInv
```

Comment: How are you generating the email?  If it's php, coldfusion, .net, whatever, use that code to get your sum.

Comment: I'm not sure how to answer that other than to say I just use HTML.  I'm sorry, I have limited knowledge about this.  I use <table> and <tr> to create the table and rows.  Does that help?

Comment: @user2607658 You need to use SUM with some kind of GROUP BY clause. Please edit the question to include your current SQL query.

Answer (score 0):

You can used the UNION operator. You need to define a column to designate the individual vs total data.

> > > **SELECT** 
> > >       dbo.CurInv.subtotal AS "subtotal",
> > >           dbo.CurInv.CIAdj AS "Adj",
> > >           dbo.CurInv.CIAdj+dbo.CurInv.subtotal+dbo.CurInv.CISTax AS "TotalInvoice",
> > >           SUM(dbo.CurInv.CIAdj) AS "Total Write Up(Down)" 
> > >       **FROM** 
> > >           dbo.Clients, dbo.CurInv 
> > >       **UNION**
> > >       **SELECT** 
> > >           SUM(dbo.CurInv.subtotal) AS "subtotal",
> > >           SUM(dbo.CurInv.CIAdj)AS "Adj",
> > >           SUM(dbo.CurInv.CIAdj+dbo.CurInv.subtotal+dbo.CurInv.CISTax) AS "TotalInvoice",
> > >           SUM(dbo.CurInv.CIAdj) AS "Total Write Up(Down)" 
> > >       **FROM** 
> > >           dbo.Clients, dbo.CurInv

Comment: I tried this and I received two errors: (8180) 37000: [Microsoft][SQL Native Client][SQL Server]Statement(s) could not be prepared. AND (1013) 37000: [Microsoft][SQL Native Client][SQL Server] the objects "dbo.CurInv" and "dbo.CurInv" in the FROM clause have the same exposed names. Use correlation names to distinguish them.  Is there any other information I could offer that might help?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up just creating a new table that calculated the totals for each row and then added that table to the query.